# Filter GCP IAM policies by description

Tags: gcloud

I'm trying to filter on IAM policies attached to a service account

```
gcloud iam service-accounts get-iam-policy foo@bar.iam.gserviceaccount.com --project foobar --filter="description:'*migration'"
```

This throws
`WARNING: The following filter keys were not present in any resource : description`

Is there a way to filter based on description of IAM policy?

EDIT: My usecase is to filter IAM policies by cluster. For SQL instances, I added a label with the cluster name but for policies returned by command `gcloud iam service-accounts` we don't have labels so I decided to add the cluster to the description and filter the cluster name through description.

Comment: IAM [Policy](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/Policy) returned by `gcloud iam service-accounts get` does not have a field `description`. [Binding](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/Policy#Binding) has an [Expr](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/Shared.Types/Expr) that includes a `description`. Is this what you're trying to filter using?

Comment: Fundamentally, you can't (!) `--filter` on a single returned resource (in this case a `Policy`). You can only filter when you have a list (even if it contains only a single element) of resources. There are solutions but please clarify what you're trying to achieve and I'll draft an answer.

Comment: Hopefully my answer has given you sufficient guidance to construct your solution. Your update didn't clarify which Resource has a `description` property that you're using (Policies don't, Policy Binding Conditions do). Policies bind identities to roles and these are decently self-documenting. If you're having to document to which cluster a policy applies, it's possible (!?) that you're policy is too broad. Corollary: the policy should describe what can do what. Good luck!

Comment: Ah, my bad. While creating a service-account we can add description (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/service-accounts/create). I'm trying to filter on this description while getting the list through `gcloud iam service-accounts get-iam-policy`

Comment: I'll update my answer with a literal solution but I don't understand why you want to do it this way. The Service Account Policy will possibly contain repeated occurrences of Service Account emails (if there are multiple role bindings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my comment above, it's unclear what you're trying to filter by.

Here's a specific solution for your stated requirement. Per my comment, it's a curious approach and I don't understand why you'd want to do this but assuming that you really do:

```bash
# List SOURCE Policy's Service Account emails
SOURCE="[SERVICE-ACCOUNT-EMAIL]"
EMAILS=$(\
  gcloud iam service-accounts get-iam-policy ${SOURCE} \
  --flatten="bindings[].members[]" \
  --filter="bindings.members:serviceAccount" \
  --format="value(bindings.members.split(\":\").slice(1:))" \
  |sort | uniq)

# Search pattern
FILTER="*migration"
# Iterate over them
for EMAIL in ${EMAILS}
do
  # Extract the Service Account's description
  DESCRIPTION=$(\
    gcloud iam service-accounts describe ${EMAIL} \
    --format="value(description)")
  if [[ ${DESCRIPTION} == ${FILTER} ]]
  then
    print "[%s] %s" ${EMAIL} ${DESCRIPTION}
  fi
done
```

Here's a solution that can be applied generally to filtering `gcloud`.

`gcloud` is complex in its use of `--format`, `--filter` and `--flatten` (see below).

`--filter` is only (!?) useful when you have multiple resources from which to filter (generally from `list` rather than `get` or `describe`) commands.

It's difficult to see this with the default output but, if you use e.g. `--format=json`, you'll immediately see that `gcloud ... get` returns one resource whereas `gcloud ... list` returns a list (`[]`).

The latter can be filtered.

There are various solutions:

###### `gcloud`

The advantage of using `gcloud` is one tool to rool them all.

Use `--flatten` to convert a single resource into a list so that you can `--filter`:

```bash
ROLE="roles/owner"
FILTER="bindings.role=\"${ROLE}\""

# Return all matching members
FORMAT="value(bindings.members[])"

# Return 1st matching member
FORMAT="value(bindings.members[0])"

# Return 1st matching member's email address
FORMAT="value(bindings.members[0].split(\":\").slice(1:))"

gcloud iam service-accounts get-iam-policy ${EMAIL} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--flatten="bindings[]" \
--filter="${FILTER}" \
--format="${FORMAT}"
```

###### [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

The UNIX philosophy is tools that do one thing and do it well. `jq` is an excellent JSON (!) processing tool and combines well with `gcloud --format=json`

```bash
FILTER="
  .bindings[]
  |select(.role==\"${ROLE}\").members[0]
  |split(\":\")[1]
"
gcloud iam service-accounts get-iam-policy ${EMAIL} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format=json \
| jq -r "${FILTER}"
```

Comment: Thanks @DazWilkin, I edited my question with the use case